# Flutter SingleChildScrollViewheight to screen height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Column and three elements in it. I set the mainAxisAlignment to MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, so that the first Element is on top of my app. The second in the middle and the third at the bottom.
Now I want to wrap that in a scroll view so that if the content of the Column is taller than the view it can be scrolled.
For example that happens when the keyboard pops up.

My code looks kinda like that:

```
Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
   children: [
      Element1(),
      Element2(),
      Element3(),
      ]
)
```

The Column expands its height over the entire screen. And that is what I also want.

But now if I wrap it in a SingelChildScrollView it shrinks to the min content height. :(

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
         Element1(),
         Element2(),
         Element3(),
         ]
   ),
)
```

Is there a way that the Column continues to expand over the entire view height of the screen and is scrollable as soon it's content is taller that the screen height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using `ConstrainedBox` and `LayoutBuilder` which will force the `Column` to take the max available height

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
          ),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Element1(),
                Element2(),
                Element3(),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: It's mostly good, have a +1, but you should remove `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, it's overwritten by the tight constraint from parent and its confusing to code readers.

Comment: It's not exactly the behavior that I want but also a good one with that I can work.
Thank you :)